FFT Magnitude Discrepancy (Python vs Swift)
I have a 1D real signal (function of time) and want to compute the power spectrum of the signal. I only want the power of the positive half of the frequency spectrum (>= 0 Hz)
My python implementation is as follows:
# Length of signal
N = len(signal)
fs = 30

# Frequency
f = np.arange(0, N // 2) * fs / N

# Power spectrum
fft_result = np.fft.fft(signal)
power = (1 / N) * np.abs(fft_result[:N//2 + 1])**2

# Normalize power
power = power / np.max(power)

My Swift implementation is as follows:
let N = signal.count
var frequencies = (0..<N/2).map { Double(fs)/Double(N)*Double($0) }
var fftMagnitudes = [Double](repeating: 0.0, count: N)

// Prepare for FFT
var realp = [Double](repeating: 0.0, count: N/2)
var imagp = [Double](repeating: 0.0, count: N/2)
var splitComplex = realp.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { realp in
        imagp.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { imagp in
             DSPDoubleSplitComplex(realp: realp.baseAddress!, imagp: imagp.baseAddress!)
            }
        }
let log2N = vDSP_Length(log2(Float(N)))
        
var signalDataAsComplex: UnsafeMutablePointer<DSPDoubleComplex>? = nil
signal.withUnsafeMutableBytes { signalDataAsComplex = $0.baseAddress?.bindMemory(to: DSPDoubleComplex.self, capacity: N) }

vDSP_ctozD(signalDataAsComplex!, 2, &splitComplex, 1, vDSP_Length(N/2))
        
// Perform FFT
let fftSetup = vDSP_create_fftsetupD(log2N, FFTRadix(kFFTRadix2))!
vDSP_fft_zipD(fftSetup, &splitComplex, 1, log2N, FFTDirection(FFT_FORWARD))
print("splitComplex", splitComplex)
        
// Compute magnitudes
vDSP_zvmagsD(&splitComplex, 1, &fftMagnitudes, 1, vDSP_Length(N/2))
print("fftMagnitudes", fftMagnitudes)
        
var power = [Double](repeating: 0.0, count: N/2)
power[0..<N/2] = fftMagnitudes[0..<N/2]
//print("power", power)
        
// Absolute value and squaring
power = power.map{ pow($0, 2) / Double(N) }
//print("power2", power)

// Normalize power spectrum
let maxPower = power.max() ?? 1.0
power = power.map { $0 / maxPower }

The power values are entirely different between both implementations and cause discrepancies in downstream tasks. Would greatly appreciate any help!
So far, I have plotted both power spectra and tested various scaling values to make them match.

Does this answer your question? Why is FFT different in Swift than in Python?
